# Load html with links into div?

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe, hyperlink

Here is the scenario:

I Have 3 files:

**index.php**:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#local").load("FarLinkLoader/farlink.php");
    });
</script>
</head><body>
<div id='local'></div>
</body></html>
```

**/FarLinkLoader / farlink.php**:

```
<div>
<a href="farfar/farfarlink.php">farfarlink</a>
</div>
```

**/FarLinkLoader / farfar / farfarlink.php**:

```
text or whatever
```

The problem is that when the **`farlink.php`** is loaded into **`index.php`** the link within **`farlink.php`** becomes invalid, the reference of the link being from **`index.php`** and not from the former file.

Is there anyway around this? **iframe** was good at this, being actually a "browser" within a browser because the page that was being loaded through iframe had it's neighbor files/directories referenced from there and not from the page within the former page was loaded as it happens in case of ajax requests.

What are the various possibilities of replacing this desired functionality?

Anticipated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you've said that "absolute URLs are not a solution", but if all your files reside on the same server, you can use URLs that aren't relative and aren't absolute with a stated domain but are absolute to the root of your server and thus would always refer to the same file regardless of what page they are contained in.  Just use a preceding "/" character and the full path from the root to each file.

Comment: so I should generate it using $_SERVER from PHP?

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about PHP to know the answer to that but I was just thinking of this as the way to write the paths that you'd have in your /FarLinkLoader/farlink.php file

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you could add a little jQuery to automatically update all the URLs in your loaded page (untested):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#local').load('FarLinkLoader/farlink.php', function() {
        $('#local').find('a').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('href', function(i,val) {
                if (val.substr(0,1)!=='/' && val.substr(0,7)!=='http://') {
                    return 'FarLinkLoader/'+val;
                } else {
                    return val;
                };
            });
        });
    });
});
```

There's also a [`<base href="...">`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4) tag you can put in the document header, but this will affect all relative links in the entire document and is probably not desirable.